# How to send a batch of transactions with --verbose-signing ledger option?

Tags: ledger

I want to use the ledger verbose signing feature recently described in this post:

https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/verbose-signing-how-to-confirm-any-tezos-operation-on-your-ledger-device-c41bd4d45ab6

Specifically I want to use it to sign a batch of transfer transactions from the CLI tezos-client. When I add the `--verbose-signing` flag, I see the Blake hash, but it is only for one transfer transaction. How do I combine transfer transactions?

Other batch payment tools create JSON for an rpc call for which `--verbose-signing` does not appear to be an option.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you create for the operation-forging-RPC is basically the information that `--verbose-signing` would give you except the hash.

You just need to compute the blake2b hash of the bytes returned by the RPC displayed as Base58 to get the same level of verification.

Here is an example of how it looks in OCaml:
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/cd72db9dd92ecb285a3631245b4e42acc4e575b8/src/bin_flextesa/command_ledger_wallet.ml#L244-250

EDIT-PS: I created this https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/578 also

Comment: I understand your suggestion to calculate the blake2b hash of the RCS JSON as Base58, but then how do I get the ledger to show the blake2b hash. That is the whole point of the `--verbose-signing` feature.

Comment: The ledger should always show the hash (unless it knows how to show all the details of the thing to sign).
Do you have an example where it doesn't?